# Fatal error using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, fatal-error

My program is extracting online data from html using Jsoup. After a few minutes, it crashes and produces the error file shown below (I could only post half of it due to character limit). I have no experience interpreting error files like this but it appears to have something to do with the Jsoup library. Any help?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f42e1d68164, pid=26375, tid=0x00007f42cc6b0700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 4653 C2 org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState$7.process(Lorg/jsoup/parser/Token;Lorg/jsoup/parser/HtmlTreeBuilder;)Z (3371 bytes) @ 0x00007f42e1d68164 [0x00007f42e1d65900+0x2864]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/students/ab123cd/crawl2/core or core.26375
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f42f0598800):  JavaThread "Thread-446" [_thread_in_Java, id=14192, stack(0x00007f42cc5b0000,0x00007f42cc6b1000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 128 (SI_KERNEL), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000064, RBX=0x00000004070f5f80, RCX=0x00000000fffffffe, RDX=0x0000000000000002
RSP=0x00007f42cc6af3b8, RBP=0x0000000000000001, RSI=0xd26f43a382b69144, RDI=0x0000000408ea9580
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x00000006afa43668, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000408ea9570
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000000000004, R14=0x00000000ffffffff, R15=0x00007f42f0598800
RIP=0x00007f42e1d68164, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x000000000000e033, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f42cc6af3b8)
0x00007f42cc6af3b8:   00000000fffffffe 0000000300000004
0x00007f42cc6af3c8:   00000006afa43650 00000006afa43650
0x00007f42cc6af3d8:   0000000408ead610 00000006a141b550
0x00007f42cc6af3e8:   00000006a141b6e0 00000004d5f486ca
0x00007f42cc6af3f8:   0000000408ea9650 00000006afa2cce8
0x00007f42cc6af408:   00000006afa43650 00000003da45a928
0x00007f42cc6af418:   0000000408ea4198 00000006afa2cce8
0x00007f42cc6af428:   0000000408ea8b58 d5f459a308ea9640
0x00007f42cc6af438:   00007f42e14ff1e4 00007f42e1101bd0
0x00007f42cc6af448:   00007f4200000000 00000006a141b550
0x00007f42cc6af458:   00007f42e14af5a4 00000006a141b6e0
0x00007f42cc6af468:   00000007c0001610 00000006afa2bc48
0x00007f42cc6af478:   00000000000502ce 00007f42d5f45793
0x00007f42cc6af488:   00007f42f869660b 00000006afa2b418
0x00007f42cc6af498:   0000000000000000 00000003d9bfc7a8
0x00007f42cc6af4a8:   00000006afa2bc48 00000006afa2b358
0x00007f42cc6af4b8:   00007f42e1101c47 00000000d5f45683
0x00007f42cc6af4c8:   00007f42e197db7c 00000007c006fc60
0x00007f42cc6af4d8:   00000006a141b550 000502ced5f4565f
0x00007f42cc6af4e8:   00000006afa2b418 00000006afa2b370
0x00007f42cc6af4f8:   00000000000a05b0 00000006afa2b390
0x00007f42cc6af508:   00007f42811d5cbd 00000006afa2b2f8
0x00007f42cc6af518:   00007f4200000000 00000006afa2b390
0x00007f42cc6af528:   00007f42d60415f1 00000007d5f4566e
0x00007f42cc6af538:   00007f42f0598800 00000006afa2b2f8
0x00007f42cc6af548:   00000000000502ce 00007f42d5f45683
0x00007f42cc6af558:   00007f42f869660b 00000007c000d4d8
0x00007f42cc6af568:   0000000000000000 00000006b016a9d8
0x00007f42cc6af578:   00000000000502ce 00000000000502ce
0x00007f42cc6af588:   00007f42e1101c47 00000006b020af88
0x00007f42cc6af598:   00007f42e1d40350 00000006afa2b358
0x00007f42cc6af5a8:   0000000000000007 000502ce00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f42e1d68164)
0x00007f42e1d68144:   49 8d 7c fc 10 66 48 0f 7e ee 41 8b d5 8b c1 2b
0x00007f42e1d68154:   ca 51 0f 4e d0 85 d2 0f 84 99 00 00 00 0f b7 07
0x00007f42e1d68164:   0f b7 0e 2b c1 0f 85 8e 00 00 00 83 fa 01 0f 84
0x00007f42e1d68174:   82 00 00 00 48 3b fe 0f 84 79 00 00 00 8b c2 83 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000064 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000004070f5f80 is an oop
[Ljava.lang.String; 
 - klass: 'java/lang/String'[]
 - length: 2
RCX=0x00000000fffffffe is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f42cc6af3b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f42f0598800
RBP=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RSI=0xd26f43a382b69144 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000408ea9580 is pointing into object: 0x0000000408ea9570
[C 
 - klass: {type array char}
 - length: 2
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000006afa43668 is an oop
[C 
 - klass: {type array char}
 - length: 4
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000408ea9570 is an oop
[C 
 - klass: {type array char}
 - length: 2
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R14=0x00000000ffffffff is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f42f0598800 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007f42cc5b0000,0x00007f42cc6b1000],  sp=0x00007f42cc6af3b8,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 4653 C2 org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState$7.process(Lorg/jsoup/parser/Token;Lorg/jsoup/parser/HtmlTreeBuilder;)Z (3371 bytes) @ 0x00007f42e1d68164 [0x00007f42e1d65900+0x2864]
C  0x00000006a141b550


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f4210028000 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17699, stack(0x00007f42bb985000,0x00007f42bba86000)]
  0x00007f4210168800 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-SocketCleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14541, stack(0x00007f42cdac5000,0x00007f42cdbc6000)]
  0x00007f42f05c7000 JavaThread "Thread-482" [_thread_in_native, id=14229, stack(0x00007f42ce1cc000,0x00007f42ce2cd000)]
  0x00007f42f05a5000 JavaThread "Thread-481" [_thread_in_native, id=14228, stack(0x00007f42cd7c2000,0x00007f42cd8c3000)]
  0x00007f42f05b2000 JavaThread "Thread-480" [_thread_in_native, id=14227, stack(0x00007f42bb884000,0x00007f42bb985000)]
  0x00007f42f05a1000 JavaThread "Thread-479" [_thread_in_native, id=14226, stack(0x00007f42cd1bc000,0x00007f42cd2bd000)]
  0x00007f42f05c9000 JavaThread "Thread-478" [_thread_in_native, id=14225, stack(0x00007f42ce4cf000,0x00007f42ce5d0000)]
  0x00007f42f05cd000 JavaThread "Thread-477" [_thread_in_native, id=14224, stack(0x00007f42cdec9000,0x00007f42cdfca000)]
  0x00007f42f025b800 JavaThread "Thread-476" [_thread_in_native, id=14223, stack(0x00007f42ccdb8000,0x00007f42cceb9000)]
  0x00007f42f05ba000 JavaThread "Thread-475" [_thread_in_native, id=14222, stack(0x00007f42ce3ce000,0x00007f42ce4cf000)]
  0x00007f42f05b8800 JavaThread "Thread-474" [_thread_in_native, id=14221, stack(0x00007f42cdbc6000,0x00007f42cdcc7000)]
  0x00007f42f05ae800 JavaThread "Thread-473" [_thread_in_native, id=14220, stack(0x00007f42ce5d0000,0x00007f42ce6d1000)]
  0x00007f42f05aa800 JavaThread "Thread-472" [_thread_in_native, id=14219, stack(0x00007f42ce8d3000,0x00007f42ce9d4000)]
  0x00007f42f05c5800 JavaThread "Thread-471" [_thread_in_native, id=14218, stack(0x00007f42cc6b1000,0x00007f42cc7b2000)]
  0x00007f42f05ac800 JavaThread "Thread-470" [_thread_in_native, id=14217, stack(0x00007f42ce9d4000,0x00007f42cead5000)]
  0x00007f42f05bf800 JavaThread "Thread-469" [_thread_in_native, id=14216, stack(0x00007f42cebd6000,0x00007f42cecd7000)]
  0x00007f42f05cb000 JavaThread "Thread-468" [_thread_in_native, id=14215, stack(0x00007f42cc09e000,0x00007f42cc19f000)]
  0x00007f42f05b6800 JavaThread "Thread-467" [_thread_in_native, id=14214, stack(0x00007f42cd0bb000,0x00007f42cd1bc000)]
  0x00007f42f023a800 JavaThread "Thread-466" [_thread_in_native, id=14213, stack(0x00007f42cceb9000,0x00007f42ccfba000)]
  0x00007f42f05bd800 JavaThread "Thread-465" [_thread_in_native, id=14212, stack(0x00007f42bba86000,0x00007f42bbb87000)]
  0x00007f42f059a000 JavaThread "Thread-464" [_thread_in_native, id=14211, stack(0x00007f42ccbb6000,0x00007f42cccb7000)]
  0x00007f42f059b800 JavaThread "Thread-463" [_thread_in_native, id=14209, stack(0x00007f42cf0f1000,0x00007f42cf1f2000)]
  0x00007f42f05bc000 JavaThread "Thread-462" [_thread_in_native, id=14208, stack(0x00007f42ce7d2000,0x00007f42ce8d3000)]
  0x00007f42f05a6800 JavaThread "Thread-461" [_thread_in_native, id=14207, stack(0x00007f42ce0cb000,0x00007f42ce1cc000)]
  0x00007f42f0590000 JavaThread "Thread-460" [_thread_in_native, id=14206, stack(0x00007f42cd5c0000,0x00007f42cd6c1000)]
  0x00007f42f05a8800 JavaThread "Thread-459" [_thread_in_native, id=14205, stack(0x00007f42cc7b2000,0x00007f42cc8b3000)]
  0x00007f42f05b4000 JavaThread "Thread-458" [_thread_in_native, id=14204, stack(0x00007f42b9662000,0x00007f42b9763000)]
  0x00007f42f05b0800 JavaThread "Thread-457" [_thread_in_native, id=14203, stack(0x00007f42ce6d1000,0x00007f42ce7d2000)]
  0x00007f42f059f800 JavaThread "Thread-456" [_thread_in_native, id=14202, stack(0x00007f42cd6c1000,0x00007f42cd7c2000)]
  0x00007f42f05a3000 JavaThread "Thread-455" [_thread_in_native, id=14201, stack(0x00007f42cd3be000,0x00007f42cd4bf000)]
  0x00007f42f0591800 JavaThread "Thread-454" [_thread_in_native, id=14200, stack(0x00007f42cd9c4000,0x00007f42cdac5000)]
  0x00007f42f05c1800 JavaThread "Thread-453" [_thread_in_native, id=14199, stack(0x00007f42cd4bf000,0x00007f42cd5c0000)]
  0x00007f42f0597000 JavaThread "Thread-452" [_thread_in_native, id=14198, stack(0x00007f42cead5000,0x00007f42cebd6000)]
  0x00007f42f0593800 JavaThread "Thread-451" [_thread_in_native, id=14197, stack(0x00007f42cdfca000,0x00007f42ce0cb000)]
  0x00007f42f058b000 JavaThread "Thread-450" [_thread_in_native, id=14196, stack(0x00007f42ce2cd000,0x00007f42ce3ce000)]
  0x00007f42f0589000 JavaThread "Thread-449" [_thread_in_native, id=14195, stack(0x00007f42cccb7000,0x00007f42ccdb8000)]
  0x00007f42f058c800 JavaThread "Thread-448" [_thread_in_native, id=14194, stack(0x00007f42cdcc7000,0x00007f42cddc8000)]
  0x00007f42f0595000 JavaThread "Thread-447" [_thread_in_native, id=14193, stack(0x00007f42cd2bd000,0x00007f42cd3be000)]
=>0x00007f42f0598800 JavaThread "Thread-446" [_thread_in_Java, id=14192, stack(0x00007f42cc5b0000,0x00007f42cc6b1000)]
  0x00007f42f05c3800 JavaThread "Thread-445" [_thread_in_native, id=14191, stack(0x00007f42ccfba000,0x00007f42cd0bb000)]
  0x00007f42f025a800 JavaThread "Thread-444" [_thread_in_native, id=14190, stack(0x00007f42cd8c3000,0x00007f42cd9c4000)]
  0x00007f42f0234000 JavaThread "Thread-443" [_thread_in_native, id=14189, stack(0x00007f42bb581000,0x00007f42bb682000)]
  0x00007f42f0275800 JavaThread "Thread-2" [_thread_in_native, id=26434, stack(0x00007f42ceeef000,0x00007f42ceff0000)]
  0x00007f42f0274000 JavaThread "Thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=26433, stack(0x00007f42ceff0000,0x00007f42cf0f1000)]
  0x00007f42f022c000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26430, stack(0x00007f42cf2f3000,0x00007f42cf3f4000)]
  0x00007f42f021f800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26429, stack(0x00007f42cf3f4000,0x00007f42cf4f5000)]
  0x00007f42f021d000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26428, stack(0x00007f42cf4f5000,0x00007f42cf5f6000)]
  0x00007f42f021b800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26427, stack(0x00007f42cf5f6000,0x00007f42cf6f7000)]
  0x00007f42f020e000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26425, stack(0x00007f42cf6f7000,0x00007f42cf7f8000)]
  0x00007f42f020c000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26424, stack(0x00007f42cf7f8000,0x00007f42cf8f9000)]
  0x00007f42f01e2000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26410, stack(0x00007f42cf8f9000,0x00007f42cf9fa000)]
  0x00007f42f01dd000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=26408, stack(0x00007f42cf9fa000,0x00007f42cfafb000)]
  0x00007f42f0009000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=26376, stack(0x00007f42f7c62000,0x00007f42f7d63000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007f42f01d3800 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f42cfafb000,0x00007f42cfbfc000] [id=26399]
  0x00007f42f022e800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f42cf1f2000,0x00007f42cf2f3000] [id=26431]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 1768448K, used 1041337K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006e3f00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1668096K, 61% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006b052cba8,0x00000006d7900000)
  from space 100352K, 16% used [0x00000006ddd00000,0x00000006decc1998,0x00000006e3f00000)
  to   space 101376K, 0% used [0x00000006d7900000,0x00000006d7900000,0x00000006ddc00000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1189941K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 65% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x000000041de0d6f8,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12906K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00007f42f50e4000,0x00007f42f703b000] byte_map_base: 0x00007f42f323a000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x00007f42f8c78f80
 Begin Bits: [0x00007f428caa0000, 0x00007f429c550000)
 End Bits:   [0x00007f429c550000, 0x00007f42ac000000)

Polling page: 0x00007f42f8caf000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=12578Kb max_used=13986Kb free=233181Kb
 bounds [0x00007f42e1000000, 0x00007f42e1e80000, 0x00007f42f0000000]
 total_blobs=3643 nmethods=3292 adapters=266
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 2049.204 Thread 0x00007f42f021b800 4980       4       org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil::parseByteData (270 bytes)
Event: 2049.336 Thread 0x00007f42f021b800 nmethod 4980 0x00007f42e1d3f490 code [0x00007f42e1d3f8c0, 0x00007f42e1d41fb8]
Event: 2069.275 Thread 0x00007f42f021f800 4983  s    3       java.lang.Throwable::initCause (64 bytes)
Event: 2069.278 Thread 0x00007f42f021f800 nmethod 4983 0x00007f42e1572a10 code [0x00007f42e1572c60, 0x00007f42e1573af8]
Event: 2069.278 Thread 0x00007f42f021f800 4981       3       sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10::run (5 bytes)
Event: 2069.279 Thread 0x00007f42f021f800 nmethod 4981 0x00007f42e143fb50 code [0x00007f42e143fd20, 0x00007f42e1440498]
Event: 2069.280 Thread 0x00007f42f021f800 4982       3       sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10::run (30 bytes)
Event: 2069.280 Thread 0x00007f42f021f800 nmethod 4982 0x00007f42e16389d0 code [0x00007f42e1638ba0, 0x00007f42e16392b8]
Event: 2209.342 Thread 0x00007f42f021f800 4984   !   3       sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor52::newInstance (53 bytes)
Event: 2209.343 Thread 0x00007f42f021f800 nmethod 4984 0x00007f42e142c790 code [0x00007f42e142c960, 0x00007f42e142cee8]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 2156.445 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=202 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1704960K, used 1679729K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006ddb80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1641984K, 100% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006d5f80000,0x00000006d5f80000)
  from space 62976K, 59% used [0x00000006d5f80000,0x00000006d845c770,0x00000006d9d00000)
  to   space 60928K, 0% used [0x00000006da000000,0x00000006da000000,0x00000006ddb80000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1082522K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 59% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x0000000417526ae0,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12905K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2156.467 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=202 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1703936K, used 36438K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006dd800000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1646592K, 0% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006d6400000)
  from space 57344K, 63% used [0x00000006da000000,0x00000006dc3958e0,0x00000006dd800000)
  to   space 59392K, 0% used [0x00000006d6400000,0x00000006d6400000,0x00000006d9e00000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1082714K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 59% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x0000000417556ae0,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12905K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2169.053 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=203 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1703936K, used 1683030K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006dd800000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1646592K, 100% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006d6400000,0x00000006d6400000)
  from space 57344K, 63% used [0x00000006da000000,0x00000006dc3958e0,0x00000006dd800000)
  to   space 59392K, 0% used [0x00000006d6400000,0x00000006d6400000,0x00000006d9e00000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1082714K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 59% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x0000000417556ae0,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12905K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2169.112 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=203 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1705984K, used 39940K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006dd980000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1646592K, 0% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006d6400000)
  from space 59392K, 67% used [0x00000006d6400000,0x00000006d8b01270,0x00000006d9e00000)
  to   space 57856K, 0% used [0x00000006da100000,0x00000006da100000,0x00000006dd980000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1082898K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 59% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x0000000417584ae0,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12905K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2181.806 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=204 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1705984K, used 1686532K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006dd980000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1646592K, 100% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006d6400000,0x00000006d6400000)
  from space 59392K, 67% used [0x00000006d6400000,0x00000006d8b01270,0x00000006d9e00000)
  to   space 57856K, 0% used [0x00000006da100000,0x00000006da100000,0x00000006dd980000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1082898K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 59% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x0000000417584ae0,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12905K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2181.859 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=204 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1707008K, used 39824K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006dd700000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1651712K, 0% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006d6900000)
  from space 55296K, 72% used [0x00000006da100000,0x00000006dc7e41d0,0x00000006dd700000)
  to   space 56320K, 0% used [0x00000006d6900000,0x00000006d6900000,0x00000006da000000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1083546K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 59% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x00000004176269e0,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12905K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2194.785 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=205 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1707008K, used 1691536K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006dd700000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1651712K, 100% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006d6900000,0x00000006d6900000)
  from space 55296K, 72% used [0x00000006da100000,0x00000006dc7e41d0,0x00000006dd700000)
  to   space 56320K, 0% used [0x00000006d6900000,0x00000006d6900000,0x00000006da000000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1083546K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 59% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x00000004176269e0,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12905K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2195.455 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=205 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1708032K, used 56306K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006e3f00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1651712K, 0% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006d6900000)
  from space 56320K, 99% used [0x00000006d6900000,0x00000006d9ffc8f0,0x00000006da000000)
  to   space 100352K, 0% used [0x00000006ddd00000,0x00000006ddd00000,0x00000006e3f00000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1189597K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 65% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x000000041ddb76f8,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12905K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2200.922 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=206 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1708032K, used 1708018K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006e3f00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1651712K, 100% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006d6900000,0x00000006d6900000)
  from space 56320K, 99% used [0x00000006d6900000,0x00000006d9ffc8f0,0x00000006da000000)
  to   space 100352K, 0% used [0x00000006ddd00000,0x00000006ddd00000,0x00000006e3f00000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1189597K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 65% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x000000041ddb76f8,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12905K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2200.968 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=206 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 1768448K, used 16134K [0x0000000671c00000, 0x00000006e3f00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1668096K, 0% used [0x0000000671c00000,0x0000000671c00000,0x00000006d7900000)
  from space 100352K, 16% used [0x00000006ddd00000,0x00000006decc1998,0x00000006e3f00000)
  to   space 101376K, 0% used [0x00000006d7900000,0x00000006d7900000,0x00000006ddc00000)
 ParOldGen       total 1829888K, used 1189941K [0x00000003d5400000, 0x0000000444f00000, 0x0000000671c00000)
  object space 1829888K, 65% used [0x00000003d5400000,0x000000041de0d6f8,0x0000000444f00000)
 Metaspace       used 12905K, capacity 13172K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1123K, capacity 1226K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 645.373 Thread 0x00007f42f0235800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f42e1a0573c method=org.jsoup.parser.CharacterReader.consumeDigitSequence()Ljava/lang/String; @ 29
Event: 1010.323 Thread 0x00007f42f01e2000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f42e1886480 method=java.lang.ref.Finalizer.remove()V @ 10
Event: 1555.132 Thread 0x00007f42f05b4000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f42e128fd80 method=org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.isElementInQueue(Ljava/util/ArrayList;Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Element;)Z @ 8
Event: 1635.974 Thread 0x00007f42f0009000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f42e17b8304 method=java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.close()V @ 18
Event: 1814.883 Thread 0x00007f42f05cd000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f42e1b3a5f8 method=java.lang.Character.codePointAtImpl([CII)I @ 8
Event: 1814.883 Thread 0x00007f42f05cd000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f42e1a89dc8 method=java.lang.Character.isBmpCodePoint(I)Z @ 4
Event: 1814.883 Thread 0x00007f42f05cd000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f42e14c04d4 method=java.lang.Character.charCount(I)I @ 3
Event: 1884.961 Thread 0x00007f42f058e800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f42e122e3f0 method=java.lang.Character.isSurrogate(C)Z @ 9
Event: 1884.961 Thread 0x00007f42f058e800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f42e167cad8 method=java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/CharBuffer;Z)Ljava/nio/charset/CoderResult; @ 105
Event: 1885.372 Thread 0x00007f42f01dd000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f42e12a1f34 method=java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Z)Z @ 104

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 522.731 Thread 0x00007f42f05c3800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0000000689a727a8) thrown at [/builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 777.668 Thread 0x00007f42f0593800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x000000069424f188) thrown at [/builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 777.683 Thread 0x00007f42f05c7000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0000000694497d60) thrown at [/builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 779.242 Thread 0x00007f42f0234000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x000000069ea52170) thrown at [/builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 785.897 Thread 0x00007f42f05b0800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0000000672966df8) thrown at [/builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 797.464 Thread 0x00007f42f025b800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006c497ab58) thrown at [/builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 804.130 Thread 0x00007f42f05a5000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0000000679a7ff18) thrown at [/builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 850.124 Thread 0x00007f42f059c000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x00000006a68b06f0) thrown at [/builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 1635.972 Thread 0x00007f42f0009000 Exception <a 'sun/net/ConnectionResetException': Connection reset> (0x00000006761bd0a0) thrown at [/builddir/build/BUILD/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 2209.724 Thread 0x00007f42f0598800 Implicit null exception at 0x00007f42e1d68164 to 0x0000000000000000

Events (10 events):
Event: 2209.518 Thread 0x00007f4210007000 Thread added: 0x00007f4210007000
Event: 2209.518 Thread 0x00007f4210007000 Thread exited: 0x00007f4210007000
Event: 2209.529 Thread 0x00007f4210007000 Thread added: 0x00007f4210007000
Event: 2209.529 Thread 0x00007f4210007000 Thread exited: 0x00007f4210007000
Event: 2209.552 Thread 0x00007f4210007000 Thread added: 0x00007f4210007000
Event: 2209.552 Thread 0x00007f4210007000 Thread exited: 0x00007f4210007000
Event: 2209.659 Thread 0x00007f4210011800 Thread added: 0x00007f4210011800
Event: 2209.660 Thread 0x00007f4210011800 Thread exited: 0x00007f4210011800
Event: 2209.675 Thread 0x00007f4210011800 Thread added: 0x00007f4210011800
Event: 2209.675 Thread 0x00007f4210011800 Thread exited: 0x00007f4210011800
```

Comment: maybe you are trying to use `too much memory`?

Comment: What HTML or XML are you parsing? Can you show us the source as well? How do you start the Java environment? Without this it is not possible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Probably is the Java heap that memory runed out...